# How to redirect to previous page after login wih multi role login

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

Here i want to try if user access the page for example /payment page, and then if the user is not login, they will direct into login form, after login they will direct into the previous page. So this is my loginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {

    $pengaturan = DB::table('pengaturan')->get();
    $menu = DB::table('menu')->get();


        return view('login_register/login',['pengaturan' => $pengaturan, 'menu'=>$menu]);
    }


    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if(!\Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password ])){
            return redirect()->back();
        }else {
            if(\Auth::user()->role=="user"){
                return redirect('/');
            }else{
                return redirect('/dashboard');
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use session to store request url and after login send use  back to that url

Comment: How do you put a role on to a `User`?

Comment: This should be be default behaviour if you use the standard Laravel auth code. Look at the authenticatesUsers trait and see how it is done normally with the `intended` property